# ROS node for compressed video with a very low latency for raspberry camera module V2

Tags: ros, raspberry-pi4, image-compression, low-latency

Im using raspberry Pi 4 B and have installed ROS melodic. I have Raspberry Pi Camera V2.1. Would like to send a compressed video with a low latency as much as possible to the Microrcontroller (ESP32) via sonar. So its important to have a very low latency as the sonar has a low bandwidth. I look at this github camera node [raspberry pi camera node for Pi Camera V2](https://github.com/UbiquityRobotics/raspicam_node) but the compressed video has a latency of more than 2 seconds. Any other way or other approaches or other help to overcome the issue with the latency?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

High latency won't necessarily affect a system with low bandwidth so long as the transmission is consistent. With any camera being processed through ROS there will almost always be *some* delay. The above node will probably be one of your best bets, however, there is the [usb cam node](http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam). If neither of these are sufficient you'll probably need to sit down and crunch the numbers to make sure you actually have enough bandwidth/processing power. Then you might want to look into creating your own video streaming node that's a little more tailor made and lower overhead; I'd suggest [gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/bindings/cplusplus.html) for this.

Comment: Im using this node [link] https://github.com/UbiquityRobotics/raspicam_node but the latency increased with the time. Why is like that?

Comment: and what kind of compression is using the approach?

Comment: I should be using the ros `image_transport` package that should just be using a compressed jpeg. Without a metric on how much it's increasing I cannot say for sure. The only reason I can think of off the top of my head is because a buffer inside ROS is filling up due to not having enough processing power.

Comment: its start from 1 sec and after 30 seconds the latency increased to 3-4 seconds

Comment: That definitely seems like the work trying to be done is too computationally expensive somewhere. The other thing to be aware of is total throughput in your system. i.e. how much bandwidth do you have available and how much are you trying to use.

Comment: But im not transmitting anything. Just processing the video on the Pi. So only publishing compressed video and when visualize the topic it has that latency. Any explanation why is like that?